# How to read the 'Name' column in a SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, jsom

I have a requirement to read the "Name" column in a SharePoint document library, tried many things but didn't really work. I am using below code to alert a lookup column and ItemID upon uploading a file in the library. Please see below screenshot for columns info on Document library.

[image]

When I checked the Internal Name of the Name column, it says: LinkFilename. Can someone help me how would I read the Name column field in the below code. THanks in advance.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ctl41_g_dbb46bd2_e248_49a1_b1b7_932ee0cf704c_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").click(function () {
            var entityid = $("select[title='Entity ID']").find("option:selected").text();
            alert(entityid);


            var itemID = getParameterByName('ID');
            alert(itemID);
            var docname =$('LinkFilename').val();
            alert(docname);
        });
    });

    function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}


</script>
```

Comment: I think internal name of **Name column** in SharePoint document library is **FileLeafRef** try using this :)

Comment: @sathish, i checked from the browser url and it says LinkFilename as of internal name. There are about 3-4 Name columns we get to work for SharePoint libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the jQuery selector (`$('LinkFilename')`) to get the field value based on its internal name? The [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) are used to get elements from the page.

Get the item based on the item id using JSOM/CSOM with [getItemById(id)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee546240.aspx) function.

[Some basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint.md)

Use “**FileLeafRef**” instead of “Name/LinkFilename” to get the file name from the item.

Comment: @JoannaW-MSFT, I already tried FileLeafref and Name using Jquery but that didn't work as well. I can't manually pass the ID and read the file name in my case. As you can see I am alerting a Lookup column value called Entity ID on click of a save button in the default edit form of a sharepoint library. So when someone uploads a document to the library I want to alert the file name of that file. Thanks again.